# sql query: create a table by merging rows from an exisiting table as follows:

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite table representing a weighted directed graph. The columns are as follows:

node1 | node2 | weight(node1,node2)

Instead I need this table:

node1 | node2 | weight(node1,node2) | weight(node2,node1)

(node2 | node1 | weight(node2,node1) | weight (node1, node2) should not exist in the table)

I am not familiar with SQL that well, so I couldn't figure out how to make the new table from the original table in sqlite3.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your node1 and node2 are integer foreign keys linking to a node table, and the table you mention is an edge table?

Assuming the edge table has been created with something like:

```
CREATE TABLE edges( node1 INTEGER, node2 INTEGER, weight REAL );
```

How about something like (assuming no self-arcs and for every link from a->b there is also a link from b->a):

```
CREATE TABLE newedges( node1 INTEGER, node2 INTEGER, weight1 REAL, weight2 REAL );

INSERT INTO newedges
    SELECT e1.node1, e1.node2, e1.weight, e2.weight
    FROM edges AS e1 INNER JOIN edges AS e2
    ON e1.node1=e2.node2 AND e1.node2=e2.node1
    WHERE e1.node1 < e1.node2;
```

The self-join collates forward and backwards edges, and the requirement that e1.node1 is less than e1.node2 ensures that you only see each collated edge once.

**Edit in response to a request to fill in zeros for missing backwards edge:**

For missing backwards edges, you can do a LEFT JOIN and use a CASE statement to fill in the gaps with zeros:

```
INSERT INTO newedges
    SELECT
        e1.node1,
        e1.node2,
        e1.weight,
        CASE WHEN e2.weight IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE e2.weight END
    FROM edges AS e1 LEFT JOIN edges AS e2
    ON e1.node1=e2.node2 AND e1.node2=e2.node1
    WHERE e1.node1 < e1.node2;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! This works for the cases where there is a backward edge for every forward edge, but this is not the case here. I would like to have zero as the weight of the backward edges in this case. Is that also possible in SQL? Sorry for not being clear in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: @user1466926. My pleasure. Stanford are currently running their database 101 course online, will help get you up to speed in a structured fashion: http://www.db-class.org/course/auth/welcome